# Orthogonality of two unit vectors

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

Suppose i have the unit vector
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3).
$$
Can i define another unit vector as
$$
(-a_2,a_1,0)/\sqrt{a_2 ^2 + a_1^2}
$$

and claim that those two vectors are orthogonal?

Comment: What if your original vector is $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: That is exactly the reason of my question. What is the problem in such definition, which makes problem for a general case?

Comment: What is the problem with it?  You run the risk of dividing by zero which isn't allowed, precisely in the case that Angina points out.

Comment: For a commonly taught general approach, see [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course, indeed by dot product

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3) \cdot \left(\frac{-a_2}{\sqrt{a_2 ^2 + a_1^2}},\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{a_2 ^2 + a_1^2}},0\right) = \frac1{\sqrt{a_2 ^2 + a_1^2}}\left(-a_1a_2+a_1a_2+0\right)=0$$

as noticed in the comments, with the condition $a_1 ^2 + a_2^2\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, but which part of my definition made this loss of generality?

Comment: @Rob Your definition is fine with the condition that $a_1 ^2 + a_2^2\neq 0$. Are you looking for a more general way to find orthogonal vectors?

Comment: @Rob again, as alluded to already, you run the risk of dividing by zero which is never allowed.  Further, you are severely limiting yourself in terms of talking only about $\Bbb R^3$ and the usual inner product while much more exotic choices of inner product spaces exist.

Comment: I thought that the zero inner product is the sufficient reason for orthogonality. I didn't know that a condition has to be defined for some cases.

Comment: @Rob The fact is that "dot product" is a special case of inner product. If you are interested in the ordinary concept of orthogonality for euclidean vectors that's fine in this way.